# program for appending a file and removing the newlines

Tags: python

i have written this program, just want to know if ti has been written properly! because I am new to this and dont know much!!

```
def read_words(words_file):
    """ (file open for reading) -> list of str

    Return a list of all words (with newlines removed) from open file
    words_file.

    Precondition: Each line of the file contains a word in uppercase characters
    from the standard English alphabet.
    """
    line = words_file.readline()
    while line != '':
        line= words_file.readline()
        words_list.append(line.rstrip('\n'))

    words_file.close()

    return words_file
```

Comment: StackOverflow is for concrete programming problems; if you'd like a general review of your code, your question may be better suited for [codereview.se]; consider posting there.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `while` loop you can use `for` loop like this.

```
words_list = []
with open('path/to/file.txt', 'r') as word_file
    lines = words_file.readline()
    for line in lines:
         words_list.append(line.rstrip('\n'))
```